# seach all inputs for a function to get only significant outputs

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I have a function `tryCatch` that outputs a p-value for different inputs defined in `ind_gene`.
Is there a way to search all inputs in `ind_gene` and get all outputs from `tryCatch` where p < 0.05

```
ind_gene <- which(rownames(matrix_cpm_spike_liver) == "hsa-miR-320c") 
s1 <- tryCatch(survdiff(
   Surv(as.numeric(as.character(ClinicalDataHep$new_death))[ind_clin],
   ClinicalDataHep$death_event[ind_clin])~
     event_rna[ind_gene,ind_tum]), error = function(e) return(NA))

> s1
Call:
survdiff(formula = Surv(as.numeric(as.character(ClinicalDataHep$new_death))[ind_clin], 
    ClinicalDataHep$death_event[ind_clin]) ~ event_rna[ind_gene, 
    ind_tum])

                                N Observed Expected (O-E)^2/E (O-E)^2/V
event_rna[ind_gene, ind_tum]=0  8        6     5.52    0.0420    0.0652
event_rna[ind_gene, ind_tum]=1 51       25    25.48    0.0091    0.0652

 Chisq= 0.1  on 1 degrees of freedom, p= 0.798
```

The p-value can be computed like this:

```
p.val <- 1 - pchisq(s1$chisq, length(s1$n) - 1)
```

Comment: `tryCatch` used in that code outputs an object that is either the result of the `survdiff`-call or has an error-class. It doesn't ever return just a "p-value". You need to describe the overall problem better and to post a data example that can be used for testing and demonstration.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: I didn't need help knowing how to build a p-value from a 'survdiff'-object. I suggested adding a data example.